$p$ has no divisors $d$ between $1 < d \leq \sqrt{p} \implies$ $p$ is prime, the contrapositive of this statement.
This is more a validative question, in particular im asking the community if my proof is valid. In number theory there is an important equivalence: let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p > 1$, then $p$ is prime $\iff$ $p$ has no divisors $d$ between $1 < d \leq \sqrt{p}$.
Im interested in proving the right to left implication by contrapositive, the reason im asking this is that i've only seen people do it directly.
WTS: $p$ has no divisors $d$ between $1 < d \leq \sqrt{p} \implies$ $p$ is prime.
The contrapositive: let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p > 1$, then $p$ is not prime $\implies$ $p$ has a divisor $d$ between $1 < d \leq \sqrt{p}$
My proof of the contrapositive:
If $p$ is not prime then $p$ is either the unit 1 or $p$ is composite.
Case 1: Suppose $p$ is the unit 1. this contradicts the fact that $p > 1$.
Case 2: Suppose $p$ is composite. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is p a product of primes. We will prove with induction that $p$ has a divisor $d$ between $1 < d \leq \sqrt{p}$. the base case is that $p$ is a product of 2 primes, since if $p$ is a product of 1 prime, then we would call it a prime number, not composite contradicting our hypothesis that $p$ is composite.
base case: Suppose $p$ is a product of two primes. There are two subcases, either the primes are equal or they are not.
subcase 1: $p$ is a product of two equal primes, say $p_{1}$. Then it follows that $p_{1} \mid p$ and that $\sqrt{p} = \sqrt{p_{1}^{2}} = p_{1}$ thus $p_{1} \in 1 < d \leq \sqrt{p}$.
subcase 2: $p$ is a product of two non equal primes, say $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$. Since primes are positive integers and they are not equal by the law of trichotomy either $p_{1} < p_{2}$ or $p_{2}< p_{1}$. Suppose without loss of generality $p_{1} < p_{2}$. We know that $p_{1} \mid p=p_{1}p_{2}$. Since $p_{1} < p_{2}$ and are positive integers it follows that $p_{1}^2 < p_{1}p_{2}$ always holds and similar for $\sqrt{p_{1}^2}<\sqrt{p_{1}p_{2}}$, (since $x < y $ and $ x, y > 1 \implies \sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt{xy}$ and clearly $p_{1}, p_{2} > 1$). Thus $1 < p_{1}= \sqrt{p_{1}^2} < \sqrt{p_{1}p_{2}} = \sqrt{p}$, thus it follows again that $p_{1} \mid p$ and $p_{1} \in 1 < d \leq \sqrt{p}$
Induction hypothesis: If $p$ is a composite number with $k$ primes the claim holds.
Induction case: Suppose $p$ is a composite number with $k+1$ primes.
Suppose $p = p_{1} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k} \cdot p_{k+1}$. Where $p_{i}$ don't have to be necessarily distinct for $i \in \{1, \ldots, k+1\}$. We know that since every $p_{i} > 1$ it follows that $\sqrt{p_{1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k}} < \sqrt{p_{1} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k+1}}$ for any $p_{i}$ that we remove. By the induction hypothesis there is a divisor $d$ of $p_{1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k}$ such that $d \in 1 < d <\leq\sqrt{p_{1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k}}$. It follows that $d \in 1 < d \leq \sqrt{p_{1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k+1}} = \sqrt{p}$ and since $d \mid p_{1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k}$ it follows easily that $d \mid p_{1} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_{k+1} = p$. Thus we have shown that the claim holds, since every composite number is a product of finitely many primes.
Since Case 1 and Case 2 hold, and the fact that if $p$ is a number then $p$ is either the unit, a prime or a composite, it follows that we have proven the contrapositive implication and since this is equivalent with the original implication we have also shown that the original implication holds.
I was wondering do you see any flaws with the proof? any tips are also welcome in terms of proof writing skills, much appreciated!

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

I'm aware that you are asking for a validation, but your proof is very long (it is ok, but very long). So let me write a shorter (and simpler) one.
If $p$ is composite, then there exists a positive integer $d_1$ such that $1<d_1<p$ and $d_1\mid p$.
Define
$$d=\begin{cases}d_1&\text{ if }d_1\le\sqrt p\\p/d_1&\text{ otherwise, that is, if $d_1>\sqrt p$}\end{cases}$$
If $d=d_1$ the statement is proven.
If $d=p/d_1$, then $p=dd_1$, so $d\mid p$. Moreover, $p=dd_1>d\sqrt p$, so $d<\dfrac p{\sqrt p}=\sqrt p$.
Alternatively, you can let $d$ be the least divisor of $p$ greater than $1$. Then, since $p/d$ is also a divisor of $p$, $d\le\dfrac pd$, so $d^2\le p$ and $d\le\sqrt p$.
Note that there is no need of explicit induction. More remarkably, there is no need of  stating that $p$ is a product of prime numbers.
On the other hand, the second proof uses the fact that the set of positive integers is well ordered (which is a consequence of the induction principle), and the first one doesn't.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs and off-topic SVs.  This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)
